# Reading sensor data - help with timing chart

Tags: clock, datasheet, image-sensor

I am reading data from a [C12880MA mini-spectrometer](https://www.hamamatsu.com/content/dam/hamamatsu-photonics/sites/documents/99_SALES_LIBRARY/ssd/c12880ma_kacc1226e.pdf) from Hamamatsu, I am having a bear of a time understanding their data sheet. *I am able* to read the data from the spectrometer, however I want to configure the integration time, the application example is short and not insightful for me.

We use three pins: clock (**CLK**), Start (**ST**) and video data (**VID** [this is the data we read (287 pixels)]).

I will show the important aspects of the data sheet below, in my program, I send a continuous clock pulse frequency at 2 MHz where I set ST high for 31 microseconds and then low for 172 microseconds, I then read the data pixel by pixel which takes about 572 microseconds where ST is low. I then repeat the loop.

[image: ..]
[image: ..]
[image: ..]
[image: ..]

Any guidance on how to get a maximum integration time and minimum would be appreciated!

Comment: Just skimming, doesn't what you posted there say that thp(ST) is 6/f? Or 6 CLK cycles? So doesn't that mean the minimum integration time is 6+48=54 CLKs? And that you can just extend ST-HIGH beyond 6 CLKs for as much more as you want beyond that? (15 nm resolution??? Yuk! That won't split the mercury 577/579 doublet. And I can split that with a DVD-RW disk in a $1 cardboard box. And have done. I'm looking at the device now. :) I use the doublets presented by a mercury argon lamp to help calibrate wavelengths.)

Comment: Hmm, guess I was thrown off by the f and not f(clk) nomenclature. You maybe right! I am interested in your project now!

Comment: Okay. Well, I have lots of papers on the topic. But I developed [this cardstock spectro](http://www.infinitefactors.org/docs/cardstock%20spectro.pdf) that you can print out on cardstock using a laserjet printer (for example) and then use scissors and glue to make. It accepts the DVD-RW dvd. The best for imaging would be to use an old style razor blade -- 2-edged -- and break it in half and then carefully place the two sharp edges as uniformly close as possible to each other while letting in just enough light. Folding lines are dashed.

Comment: You can also see [Fluorescence Spectroscopy in a Shoebox](http://www.infinitefactors.org/docs/Fluorescence%20Spectroscopy%20in%20a%20Shoebox,%20Wahab.pdf) by Wahab. Worth reading. Also, [Planar double-grating microspectrometer](http://www.infinitefactors.org/docs/Planar%20double-grating%20microspectrometer,%20Grabarnik%20et%20al.pdf) by Grabarnik et al.

Comment: Finally, make sure to read the paper I used to create the cardstock spectro: [A DVD Spectroscope: A Simple, High-Resolution Classroom Spectroscope](http://www.infinitefactors.org/docs/A%20DVD%20Spectroscope:%20A%20Simple,%20High-Resolution%20Classroom%20Spectroscope.pdf) by Wakabayashi and Hamada. I highly recommend that you write the authors. I did so. Very helpful folks.

Comment: Grabarnik has another very interesting article. See: [Optimal implementation of a microspectrometer based on a single flat diffraction grating](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18425182/). My central point though is that if these things ***are*** interesting, then write the authors. If they haven't yet died, they will be very helpful to you and can refer you to just about anything you need.

Comment: We live in remarkable times where it is possible to build fabulous physics tools for almost no money. I am using parts from a retired laser printer, for example, to demonstrate and measure the difference in the speed of light between air/vacuum and water. Pretty much everything you need is already there in simple parts to duplicate the actual original experiments performed many many decades ago at very high cost and time, then.